# How MS Visual Studio updates the language SDKs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I was wondering, the new language features added in C++, are available in old versions of `Microsoft Visual Studio`? How `VS` versions update the language SDKs?

Comment: You should probably re-phrase this question in terms of specific VC versions. "old" is too vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the new C++11 features which are added to the compiler are only in the newest version. Even the latest verions [VS2012] doesn't currently support all of C++11 yet though - see [here for the list](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx)

Some parts of C++11 (previously called TR1 and then into C++0x) were added to VS2010 at the time - std::shared_ptr, unordered associative containers, etc.

[Disclosure - I work for MS but have nothing to do with the compiler team, answer is from public sources only]